# iOS Swift - CLLocationManager only displays on one of two ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I am successfully using CLLocationManager on ViewController01 (inital viewcontroller) to display the users location on a MapView. However, the same CLLocationManager code in ViewController02 does not display the blue dot representing the users location on the Mapview.

If I designate ViewController02 as the initial viewcontroller, then ViewController01 doesn't display the blue dot...

It seems that the initial VC has a hold of the "locationManager" and I can't create another instance of it in another VC even if I use "locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()" on the initialViewController... Any ideas?

Thank you,
Robert

Comment: you should post some of your code. By the way, if you are using MKMapView you can simply set property showUserLocation (maybe I misspelled it) and you don't need CLLocationManager

Comment: Thanks Andriy! (showUserLocation property) I will look into that. As for posting code... I thought about that but there's too much and I thought it would be better to summarize my issue instead.

Comment: Andriy, I was using that property in "didChangeAuthorizationStatus" and it was not getting fired on the second VC. I added "showUserLocation" to viewDidLoad and "required init" and it works!!! Thank you for prompting that experiment!!!

Answer (score 0):

I remember having this problem some time ago. I did not solve it but I used this instead:

[One Shot Location Manager](https://github.com/icanzilb/OneShotLocationManager)

Working with location managers became a breeze after that.